# JSON partial string

Tags: ios, json, uitableview

How can i return the part of a string in a cell in Xcode?

I have a json responce:

```
{"Email":"john@appleseed.com","Password":"4321","lijst":"eieren, kaas, melk, 2 uien, brood(volkoren)"}
```

how can i get the value's at "lijst" in different cells in xcode?
So cell 1 = Eieren
cell 2 = Kaas
etc...

this is the code to display it all in one cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (!cell)
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
        cell.textLabel.text = [self name];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Name";
        break;
    case 1: {
        NSString *email = [details objectForKey:@"Email"];
        if (!email)
            email = @"No email";
        if ([email isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
            email = @"<Multiple emails>";
        cell.textLabel.text = email;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Email";
        break;
    }
    case 2:
        cell.textLabel.text = self.details[@"lijst"];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"List";
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

return cell;
```

}

Comment: You'd use NSJSONSerialization to parse the JSON string into an NSDictionary.

Comment: And then use [`-[NSString componentsSeparatedByString:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString:) to split the string into an NSArray of NSStrings.

Comment: As to "eieren, kaas, melk,...", that's a single character string and you'd have to parse it yourself, using one of the NSString functions, probably.

Comment: im not very familiar with objective - C, i know in R there is a function that separates on  what ever u put between quotation marks. 
is there anything like that in C?  Could u give an Example

Comment: Please refer to the documentation!  There is some pretty good documentation available for the Objective-C library, and you should learn to refer to it *first*, before coming to SO to ask advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you have parsed this JSON into a dictionary called `self.details`. You could then, as @bdesham pointed out, get an array of the individual values with `componentsSeparatedByString:`. For example, if you had a `NSArray` property called `lijstArray`, you could do something like:

```
NSString *lijstString = self.details[@"lijst"];
self.lijstArray  = [lijstString componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
```

Then, `lijstArray[0]` will have the first value, `lijstArray[1]` the second, etc. The number of values is `[lijstArray count]`.

The above only works if you know that there will be exactly one and only one space after the commas. If you don't know that for sure, you'd just use `@","` for the separator, but then trim the whitespace. For example, if you declared the `lijstArray` property to be a `NSMutableArray`, you could do something like:

```
NSString *lijstString = self.details[@"lijst"];
NSArray  *tempArray   = [lijstString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

self.lijstArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *lijstValue in tempArray) {
    [self.lijstArray addObject:[lijstValue stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];
}
```

Whichever approach you adopt, having populated an array, `lijstArray`, you can now use that in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. For example, let's assume your tableview had two sections, section 0 being the name and email, and section 1 being the individual `lijstArray` values, e.g.:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0)
        return 2;
    else if (section == 1)
        return [self.lijstArray count];

    return 0;  // we never should get here, but in the spirit of defensive programming, let's make sure we handle this
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
                cell.textLabel.text = [self name];
                cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Name";
                break;
            case 1: {
                NSString *email = [details objectForKey:@"Email"];
                if (!email)
                    email = @"No email";
                if ([email isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
                    email = @"<Multiple emails>";
                cell.textLabel.text = email;
                cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Email";
                break;
            }
            default:
                break;
        }
    } else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        cell.textLabel.text = self.lijstArray[indexPath.row];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked.
if i wanted to auto increment should i just make a for loop
like for(i = 0; i < [lijstValues count]; i++)
Case i:
....

Comment: @brian Not quite, I don't think. If you want to show these individual values as cells in your table, you'd want to put these values in an array that you'll set up as a class property, e.g. `lijstArray`, and then modify your `UITableViewDataSource` methods to grab the individual items appropriate for the respective row of the table. See revised answer for example of what you might do if you wanted to show these in individual table view cells.

Comment: I see where you are going, however this gives me the error of LijstValues not found, if i create a property of it, say NSArray *lijstValues, it works but then gets stuck in the addObject: asking me if i want to use _lijstValues.

Comment: @brian sorry for the typo. I changed that variable name in my code samples, and didn't fix it everywhere. Call your array property whatever you want, and then use it accordingly. See revised answer, where I use `lijstArray` throughout. But the idea is simple: Create array property, populate it as you parse the result from the server, and then use that array in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.